# GCM and app updates: should I be re-registering in every activity or just the main one?

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Ok, so I know that if the app gets updated, I should re-register with GCM because the old key might be invalid at that point. My question is, when an app updates, are all open activities closed and can I count on the main activity being started again (ie i can just put the version check & re-register in the onCreate of that activity), or are all the open activities going to continue running and I have to put that re-register check in all the onStarts of those activities? (sorry i dont have an android phone to test this out with and emulators dont connect to google play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When any app is being updated, if that app is already running, the OS will force close it, then proceed with the installation of your update. Once update is finish, you have the chance to 'Open' it. This is when your main or home activity will do the version check, and re-register with GCM server.